# Can't create a Facebook app : Missing App Integration

Tags: android, facebook, integration

I have trouble creating a FacebookApp. We have made an Android game and when the user touches a Facebook logo, it posts a msg on the user's wall and in returns we grant him premium stuffs.

BUT *I'm unable to create the FaceBookApp*

In admin mode, when I got to "App Center", there is a red square with this message in it :

**[**

**Missing App Integration.**

**Before setting up your app detail page, you must specify how your app integrates with Facebook. Click here to vist your apps settings page to manage your integrations**

**]**

If I click on the link, it brings me to the place where you choose how to integrate your app into Facebook.

I selected only 
**"Native Android App"**

and for options I chosed :

1. Single-Sign-On [Disabled]
2. Deep linking [Disabled]
3. Android key hash = I put the right one in place
4. Android Package name = ""
5. Android class name  = ""

On this page, if I click on "**Confirm**" it says to me "Ok, it went well" but when I come back to App Center there is still the red square telling me I need to specify how my app integrates with Facebook :(

Can anyone please help me on this one ?

Thx you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily to create an app in facebook app center for posting msgs on wall (or etc). I'm creating a game with facebook support too and it's posting photo with link and caption but game is not added to facebook app center for the same issue.

First of all, i created an app on https://developers.facebook.com/apps where we should to remember AppId (API KEY), than enable app for Android tab and enter Hashcode. Hashcode maded of your keystore by using command `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64` where "androiddebugkey" is the name of your key (for export) and "~/.android/debug.keystore" is your keystore (for export ofc).

There is my class that's posting photo

```
public class EveryBodyActivity extends Activity {

    public final String API_KEY = "YOUR API KEY HERE";
    public final String[] permissions = {"publish_stream"};
    Facebook facebook = new Facebook(API_KEY);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                authorizeAndPostMassage();
            }
        });
    }

    public void authorizeAndPostMassage() {
        facebook.authorize(this, permissions, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new DialogListener () {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    Toast.makeText(EveryBodyActivity.this, "Authorization successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    postMassage();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                Toast.makeText(EveryBodyActivity.this, "Facebook error, try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                Toast.makeText(EveryBodyActivity.this, "Error, try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                //Этот коллбэк никогда не срабатывает, вероятно, ошибка в SDK
                Toast.makeText(EveryBodyActivity.this, "Authorization canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }});
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    private void postMassage() {
        Bundle imageBundle = new Bundle();
        imageBundle.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
        imageBundle.putString("method", "photos.upload");
        imageBundle.putString("caption", "New Voodoo Doll");

        byte[] data = null;

         Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        data = baos.toByteArray();
        imageBundle.putByteArray("picture", data);
        Toast.makeText(EveryBodyActivity.this, "Sending VooDoo...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {

            facebook.request(null, imageBundle, "POST");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (fileNotFoundException.getMessage()), 100);
        } catch (MalformedURLException malformedURLException) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (malformedURLException.getMessage()), 100);

        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (ioException.getMessage()), 100);
        }
        }
```

Comment: You should at least specify **how** you are doing it then or post a link to the right part of the documentation.

Comment: I must add that we use the prime31 plugin for Android : "Social Networking". In their [doc](http://www.prime31.com/unity/docs/#socialAndroidDoc), it reads "Facebook requires you to create a key hash and store it on their servers so they can validate your application"

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the "Configured for Android SSO" option.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/270177039756846/